# Firebase Multiple Authentication triggered functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have 2 functions hooked to same trigger. I am only seeing one of them trigger when new user signs up. Is this known limitation? i dont have any errors in the logs.

My two functions look like this:

```
//utils/emailer.js
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  ...
  return sendWelcomeEmail(email, displayName);
});




//user/index.js
exports.onUserCreated = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

 ...
});
```

my index.js

```
"use strict";

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.constants = require('./constants');
exports.emailers = require('./utils/emailer');  //utils/emailer.js
exports.userFunctions = require('./user');      //users/index.js
```

Comment: we could have multiple functions to execute for same trigger by deploying two different functions with the same trigger. You could check the function triggers and logs in firebase `Function Logs` console.

Comment: As Muthu said: this is not a limitation that I'm aware of. I'm actually not sure if either if your functions will be detected when deploying as I think they may be getting nested into other exports. You might want to check the logs you get when you deploy these functions, and the invocation logs in the console.

Comment: Ok Logs in Google Cloud Platform shows logs from emailer.js as well. For some reason I was not noticing it in Firebase functions log section. 
I have auth error using nodemailer thats why emails are not getting sent. thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Firebase function limitations, both functions trigger ok.